skipped code when it be invoke from other pipeline
i have a pipeline1 that execute a bash script block success and run ok,BUT when i invoke this pipeline1 from pipeline2 the bash script block didn't executed.
Other sh individual line commands yes run ok and it showed output but all commands in for statement into block script not be are executing
Any idea?
I am referencing to this:
pipeline1
  steps { 
        script{
          <commands> 
          echo "Hello world"
          sh '''#!/bin/bash
          sh "echo Hello1 world"
          for i in $var do
          <commands1> 
          sh "echo Hello2 world"
          if ... ;then
            sh "echo Hello3 world"
            <commands2> 
          else
            sh "echo Hello4 world"
            <commands3> 
          fi
          sh "echo Hello5 world"
          <commands4> 
          done
          sh "echo Hello6 world"
          <commands5> 
          '''
          sh "echo Hello7 world"
        }
    }

pipeline2
steps { 
            build (job: '../../folfer1/pipeline1', parameters: [ 
            ... 
            ], wait: true) 
} 

Then, the output on pipeline2 showed
            echo "Hello world"
            echo 'Hello1 World'
            echo 'Hello6 World'
            echo 'Hello7 World'

but *not executing code locate into for statement in sh block bash and not showed any error, only showed Hello world, Hello1 world, Hello6 world and Hello7 world
reproduction
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/folder/pipeline2
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] ansiColor
[Pipeline] {

[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Executing playbook pipeline2)
[Pipeline] withEnv
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
<commands>
[Pipeline] echo
Hello world
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo 'Hello1 world'
Hello1 world
+ echo 'Hello6 world'
Hello6 world
+ <commands5>
[Pipeline] echo
Hello7 world
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // withEnv
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }

[Pipeline] // ansiColor
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS

Resume:
if i invoke this pipeline1 from pipeline2 all commands in for statement into block script not be are executing but, if I running pipeline1 alone the result and all executions are ok!)
Update
I change defined sh bash block code
sh '''#!/bin/bash
<commands>
'''

by
sh """
<commands>
"""

and get same situation.
Thanks in advance
Regards,
Edu < allways learning

Well, i found the mistake about that.
I forgot add a value from pipeline parameter of the pipeline2 that I use into variable that after it be used  on for statement.
